# Need php-cgi process to show site URL too?

Tags: linux, php-fpm, sysadmin

I have a CentOS 7 server.  When I use "top" to view processes I can hit "c" to get the full command.  I then see something like this:

```
17890 do1803    20   0 R 100.0  0.6   0:02.39 /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/do1803/public_html/site.com/index.php                                
17905 do1803    20   0 R 100.0  0.5   0:01.95 /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/do1803/public_html/site.com/index.php                                
17956 do1803    20   0 R 100.0  0.3   0:01.00 /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/do1803/public_html/site.com/index.php
```

I then setup a new Almalinux 8.8 server and do the same thing with top.  But the full command is only:

```
17890 do1803    20   0 R 100.0  0.6   0:02.39 /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

I don't see the URL like ...public_html/site.com/index.php now.

What can I change to see what the URL/path is that php-cgi is calling under Almalinux?  Why is is missing?